# variables accesable in anonymous javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, anonymous-function

I have a problem to access temp in the anonymous function. the toggle works just fine. This is the workaround because I was not able to set callback functions to the `.toggle()`

I would wish to `.toggle("drop", 200, function(){});` and in the function I call the second toggle to show the element when the text changed. I wasn't getting this working so I tried the `setTimeout` workaround but this won't work as well. Please tell me how can I access temp in it or how can I use the callback of `.toggle()`?

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var temp = array[i].split("&");

  setTimeout(function(){
    $('td[vvalue="'+temp[0] + '"] > a').text("A");
  }, 300);

  $('td[vvalue="'+temp[0] + '"]').toggle("drop", 200);
  $('td[vvalue="'+temp[0] + '"]').toggle("drop", 200);
}
```

Comment: Seems like your particular problem here is closures...

Comment: in your setTimeout, `var temp` is shared between all your functions in the loop, therefore `var temp`  will always point to the last element it was set to in that loop

Comment: But that is what i warnt to do, array.length times Take a String and Split it in the temp array and use temp[0] to get the Name of the vvalue. Tell me what i have to change to get it working please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it could be an issue with your selector rather than the temp value in the function:

```
$('td[vvalue="'+temp[0] + '"] > a').text("A");
```

should probably be:

```
$('td[value="'+temp[0] + '"] > a').text("A");
```

Notice the spelling error on "value".  td elements do not have a value attribute.  You may want to rethink your markup.  If you need a custom attribute, html5 has the new data- attributes for custom attributes.

Comment: no, e.g. the  toggle() works just fine, its an abbreviation for virtualvalue